# Number of chars in search?

Tags: geonetwork, search

Is there a limit of how many chars that can be used in a GeoNetwork search?

We have a card called `"Grönområden inom 200m för förskolor 300m för skolor ÖP 2030 rev 2018"`, 69 characters long. It is possible to write that in the search field but it won't display as a result.

Is there a limit of 50 characters or so?

Comment: I have a GeoNetwork 3.8.0.0 instance and search for `Arctic Northern Europe-Russia GSC EN 1:5M Onshore Bedrock Geology` (which is 65 characters) and I get two results in my catalogue, so if there is a limit, it doesn't look like it's 50 characters.  What happens if you search for `Grönområden inom 200m för förskolor 300m för skolor ÖP 2030 rev 2`

Comment: Sorry to say it doesn't help to stop after "rev 2". When i start to type "Grönområden" there is a dropdown with 2 choices so the look up works. Strange

Comment: Could it be something to do with character set? just a thought